# http response code for SSL sites asp

Tags: c#, .net, https, httpresponse

I am trying to create a windows application to send alert if a website is down, i first wrote this rudimentary form to check if it was working.

```
HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);
httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();

if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It works.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not able to ping");
}
httpRes.Close();
```

it worked fine but when i wanted to do the same for SSL sites (https) it didnt work, i looked it up and added

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
```

but still im not able to get any response from the https sites, i tried many sites so i dont think its the problem with sites, im a newbie in .net any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do specify "https" in the url, don't you? What do do see when you step through the code (with the debugger)? What is in the Response?

Comment: The certificate is accepted but the value of httpres is still set to null.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem guys, the https was responding with 200 (OK) whereas http was responding with 302(Found) so i just modified my condition to add 200 to it it works like a charm. For anyone interested in the working code, here it is

```
      public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
        HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);
        httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;


            HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();

            if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || httpRes.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.Found)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It works.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not able to ping");
            }
            httpRes.Close();
       }
```

Regards,
Prasanth